# Mysql: optimistic locking failed when calling save with JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have no locking defined and I can't figure out why I get this error when updating an attribute of `User` entity:

```
Object of class [com.****.User] with identifier [2df1fe02-e679-4c5e-bc9c-c023e5be1460]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.****.User#2df1fe02-e679-4c5e-bc9c-c023e5be1460]
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55712', transport: 'socket'
```

It happens just when calling save on the `user` instance:

```java
User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
user.setMonthlyThreshold(monthlyThreshold);
userRepository.save(user);
```

User repository is defined as follows:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUserName(String username);
}
```

User class:

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = USER_USERNAME)
    private String userName;
...// other attributes
```

What am I missing?

I'm using MySQL DB, Spring Boot, java 8.

Comment: How does the @Version field look like?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have any version related fields, attributes :(

Comment: And do you have an concurrent requests?

Comment: Nothing at all. I just start-up the SpringBoot app locally from IntelliJ, then hit the end-point with Postman.

Comment: I also have these 2 lines in `application.properies`: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Comment: I think the cause is GenerationType.AUTO and UUID as type. UUID is not supported out of the box with JPA and GenerationType.AUTO should be avoided.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli if I'm not mistaken, the default strategy type is `AUTO`, so what can we use in this case?

Comment: Because even after removing `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`, it raised the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219956/discussion-between-simon-martinelli-and-belgoros).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was extracted from this [blog article](https://phauer.com/2016/uuids-hibernate-mysql/) and looks like this:

```java
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;
...
```